# static method vs static data

Tags: java, oop

Why cant we use non static data members within a static method?

Comment: I can't understand your question. **outside a static method within a static method**

Comment: presumably: why can't we use, within a static method, non-static data members declared outside that method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non static members belong to an object.  A static method has no object.

If we have

```
class MyClass {
int member;
. . .

public static int statFunc() {
   . . .
   foo = member;
   . . .
}
. . .
```

}

If we have two instances of `MyClass` one where `member = 1` and another where `member = 2`
and we call `statFunc` then statFunc has no idea which value of `member` to use.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static data types refer to the instance of a class, the values of these variables can vary over each instance one creates from the class.

For example look at the following code:

```
public class name {

String name;

}
```

Each name object can have a different name.

This is why non-static variables can only be accessed by non-static methods, otherwise a static method would never know which instance variable is ment.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Because it doesn't make any sense. Instance variables are associated with an instance of the class. Static methods aren't. Which instance's variables would you be talking about within the static method?